# Show related topics when creating a new documentation topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation

It's day one of documentation in public beta, and there have already been a few duplicate posts, which end up just being deleted later.

Although there *is* a faint warning to search before submitting something to documentation, it really doesn't do much

[image: THIS IS MY IMAGE DESCRIPTION]

I propose that we have something like we do on Q&A, where related questions are shown while typing

[image]

Although there is the argument that the duplicates could just be merged with existing topics, this does not hold true in the event of exact duplications (or where the existing documentation is already better).

Comment: We have a lookup on *requesting* a new topic. Sounds like a good idea for just straight up creating one as well. Thanks!

Comment: I think that this would also be a good idea for when creating examples, I have come across multiple examples which are basically not as good versions of whole detailed topics that already exist.